# How to get mysqlx npm package?

Tags: mysql, node.js, npm, npm-install

I want to use MySQL document store. For this, I have gone through [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/x-devapi-userguide/en/database-connection-example.html). As per documentation, I need to use 'mysqlx' npm package. But when I searched for 'mysqlx' package on [npm website](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=mysqlx). I got '[@mysql/xdevapi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mysql/xdevapi)' package. I am confused which npm package should I use for MySQL document store.

Kindly suggest.

Comment: please let me know if I am missing anything? If you are marking question negative, give explanation what is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [Changes in MySQL Connector/Node.js 1.0.4 (2016-10-10, Milestone 3)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-nodejs/en/connector-nodejs-news-1-0-4.html):
>
> - Changed package name from `mysqlx` to `@mysql/xdevapi`

---

- In our application folder copy the MySQL [Connector/Node.js](https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-Nodejs/mysql-connector-nodejs-1.0.5.tar.gz) tar.gz file.
- Once it has copied, run the following command to add the package to our application:

  ```js
  $ npm install mysql-connector-nodejs-1.0.5.tar.gz
  ```

---

From MySQL [Connector/Node.js](https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-Nodejs/mysql-connector-nodejs-1.0.5.tar.gz)::`README.md`:

```txt
Installation
------------
This library is organized in a way that it can be installed using Node.js's npm
tool into your project:
  `npm install mysql-connector-nodejs-1.0.5.tar.gz`
or diectly from npmjs.com:
  `npm install @mysql/xdevapi`
Please refer to http://npmjs.com for more information on npm.
```

Comment: thanks wchiquito. This was helpful. Can we able to perform parameter binding on find method using this?. As per documentation, it allows us to do that. But when I tried that using simple parameter binding, I failed to do so. Even "like" comparison operator is not working in my case.

Comment: @Shri.harry: What error is indicated?. See [Bug #82265 Error when mysqlx tries to parse expression (Nodejs)](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=82265). See [3.4 Parameter Binding](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/x-devapi-userguide/en/parameter-binding.html).

Comment: Hi @wchiquito I have downloaded the @mysql/xDevApi from npm repository npmjs.com/package/@mysql/xdevapi and its version is 1.0.5. I am getting same error as mentioned in post.

Comment: @Shri.harry [Bug #84584 Unable to bind parameters](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=84584).